# How to join the threads to main thread in threadpool?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using thread pool to run the task in different process,to join all the threads to main thread I am doing like below ,But it's taking more time to give result.How to achieve this in efficient way.

```
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        Runnable sendded = new com.treamis.hr.employee.Sendded(filePath, academicyearmaster);
        executor.execute(sendded);

        Runnable employeeAttendanceReport = new EmployeeAttendanceReport(filePath2);
        executor.execute(employeeAttendanceReport);
        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
        }
        System.out.println("Finished all threads");
```

Comment: First polling for termination status of the executor is not right. Use awaitTermination() method instead.
As far as the termination time, it depends on how long the running tasks take to stop. Could you please post the `EmployeeAttendanceReport` code?

Answer (score 2):

I would use `Future` for this task. Use `executor.submit(yourrunnable)` instead of `executor.execute(yourrunnable)` which will return you a `Future`. When you reuse these future objects somehow in you main thread it will have to wait untill all your threads are done.

[EDIT] Here's an example:

```
Future future = executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Asynchronous task");
    }
});

future.get();  //returns null if the task has finished correctly.
```

(taken from http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html)

Comment: +1, and BTW: When multiple tasks have to be submitted, one can conveniently put them into a collection and pass this collection to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection- - this will wait automatically until all tasks are completed.

Comment: How to put all the objects into the collection and call.

Answer (score 0):

By doing that while not shutdown you will tax the CPU because it will just perform that method call as fast as it can until it returns true.

Either put a small Thread.sleep or even better, call awaitTermination on the executor

I believe there are examples in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Comment: Could you please explain me with my above example.

Comment: for both the methods need time of execution.

Comment: Executor.shutdown waits for all the running jobs to finish if I recall correctly